# PHP MAILER GMAIL SMTP ERROR

Tags: php, email, smtp, phpmailer

I am currently in testing mode for my project and have setup the PHPMAILER (ver 5.2.9) library and would like to generate e-mails using the Gmail SMTP.

I have setup the script on my local system but when the script is executed it keeps waiting for the localhost to respond even though i have specified the smtp server address.

I am currently using the following:

PHP version 5.4.7
xampp version 1.8.1 (it's dated, i know)
phpmailer version - 5.2.9

below is the script:

```
require 'phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = 'xxxx@gmail.com';
$mail->Password = 'xxx';
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->Port = 587;

$mail->From = 'xxx@gmail.com';
$mail->FromName = 'test';
$mail->addAddress('xxx@outlook.com');
$mail->WordWrap = 50;
$mail->isHTML(true);
$mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
$mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message has been sent';
}
```

thanks

Comment: Your code looks ok, but you need to post the actual error.

Comment: hi synchro, the borwser keeps waiting for a response from the localhost. i waited for a few minutes but no response. if i change "tls" to "starttls" then it gives  an error but due to charachter length limitation i'm unable to post it here. but at the end it says:
Message could not be sent.Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed.

Comment: Don't post big things like that in comments - they are not very readable. Edit your question instead. In this case it looks like your PHP is compiled without SSL, so there's not much you can do until you add SSL. The setting should be `tls` or `ssl`; `starttls` is not a valid option.

Comment: thanks for the tip synchro. i'm new here. will edit questions going forward.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be :

```
require 'phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

  $mail = new PHPMailer;
  //Tell PHPMailer to use SMTP
  $mail->isSMTP();
  //Enable SMTP debugging
  // 0 = off (for production use)
  // 1 = client messages
  // 2 = client and server messages
  $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
  //Ask for HTML-friendly debug output
  $mail->Debugoutput = 'html';
  //Set the hostname of the mail server
  $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
  //Set the SMTP port number - 587 for authenticated TLS, a.k.a. RFC4409 SMTP submission
  $mail->Port = 587;
  $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
  $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
  $mail->Username = "username@gmail.com";
  $mail->Password = "yourpassword";

  //Set who the message is to be sent from
  $mail->setFrom('from@example.com', 'First Last');
  $mail->addReplyTo('replyto@example.com', 'First Last');
  $mail->addAddress('whoto@example.com', 'John Doe');
  $mail->WordWrap = 50;                                 
  $mail->isHTML(true);                                  
  $mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
  $mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
  $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

  if(!$mail->send()) {
      echo 'Message could not be sent.';
      echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
  } else {
      echo 'Message has been sent';
  }
```

There is no option for `$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;`

Comment: Yes there is. Also 4.

Comment: hi hardik, the borwser keeps waiting for a response from the localhost. i waited for a few minutes but no response. if i change "tls" to "starttls" then it gives an error but due to charachter length limitation i'm unable to post it here. but at the end it says: Message could not be sent.Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed.

Answer (score 0):

So it seems that the problem was with a setting in php.ini file. un-commented ;extension=php_openssl.dll by removing the preceding ; and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your phpmailer script is running ok, if there is no problem with mailer then login with your gmail account and goto ->gmail setting .
Now check the allow less secure option in gmail setting.
By default its off

Allow less secure apps: OFF

Make sure that this setting is ON.

Once it done now run your script from browser.

if you do not found link click here to go 
 https://myaccount.google.com/security#activity

Answer (score 0):

```html
Try if SMTP issues + using TSL+ Gmail
<?php
include'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

include "PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php"; // include the class name
$mail = new PHPMailer(); // create a new object
$mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP

$mail->SMTPOptions = array(
    'ssl' => array(
        'verify_peer' => false,
        'verify_peer_name' => false,
        'allow_self_signed' => true
    )
);

//$mail->SMTPDebug = 1; // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
//$mail->SMTPDebug = 2; // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // authentication enabled
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for GMail
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->Port = 587; // or 587
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Username = "mygmail@gmail.com"; 
$mail->Password = "mypassword";
$mail->addReplyTo("mygmail@gmail.com","user");
$mail->SetFrom("mygmail@gmail.com","My Site");
$mail->Subject = "Your Gmail SMTP Mail";
$mail->Body = "Hi, your first SMTP mail via gmail server has been received.";
$mail->AddAddress("your@gmail.com");
 if(!$mail->Send()){
  echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
else{
    echo "Message has been sent";
}
?>
```